# How to avoid running login flow for every detox test?

Tags: react-native, testing, end-to-end, detox

I have a chat app where I have to login and go to chat screen. I have written a login test in login.spec.js file. Then I have to test other feature like sending and receiving message. I have written that test as well in a separate test suite message.spec.js. But when I run detox it opens two ios simulators and the message test fails. How do I structure detox so that it first runs login suite and then tests the send message flow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.